# Objective-C: How Can I Format a float value to Only Display The Decimal, Without The Full Figure, or Decimal Point?

Tags: objective-c, time, cocos2d-iphone, floating-point

There are MANY Q&A's for limiting to only 2 decimal places, to the point of over saturation.

However, I would like to format my float to only get the decimal value.

I'm making a stopwatch, and currently have this...

```
@implementation HudLayer
{
    CCLabelTTF *_label; 
    float timer;
}

-(void)update:(ccTime)delta { if (_isTimerActive)
    {
        timer += delta;

        NSNumber *theDouble = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:timer];
        float miliseconds = timer;
        int inputSeconds = [theDouble intValue];
        int hours =  inputSeconds / 3600;
        int minutes = ( inputSeconds - hours * 3600 ) / 60;
        NSString *theTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d:%.2d:%.2f", hours, minutes, miliseconds];

        [_label setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %@", theTime]];
    }
}
```

However, the issue I'm having is that the timer reads out put on to the label showing the full seconds...

00:14:865.35

Instead it should just be:

00:14:05.35

HH:MM:SS.ms

My first thought was to just drop the decimal from the outputted float, and manually calculate seconds as i do hours and minutes...

Any advice? Thanks...

Comment: you use an NSNumberFormatter on the label. there are also better methods for dealing with precise timing than floats...

Comment: What do you want to receive instead of "00:14:865.35" ?

Comment: Edited question to show desired output***

Comment: @user3601508 what do you have in 'timer'? seconds or miliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
timer += delta;

float float_seconds = timer;
int seconds = float_seconds;
int hours = seconds / 3600;
int minutes = seconds / 60 % 60;
NSString *theTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d:%.2d:%05.2f", hours, minutes, float_seconds - ( seconds / 60) * 60];
NSLog(theTime);

[_label setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %@", theTime]];
```